# Parameters to STL list::insert

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, pass-by-value

The syntax of STL list::insert is as below -

```
  iterator
  insert(iterator __position, const value_type& __x);
```

Why a **iterator** instead of a **reference to an iterator** is being passed?

Comment: Iterators are conventionally passed by value in C++ rather than by reference.  I'm not sure where this convention arose, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB the reason i asked this because normally a reference to a const is preferred to avoid temporaries (and copy constructors). But as templatetypedef mentions - this is by convention and Potatoswatter explains in the comments below that compiler optimizes the call, may be that speaks for the convention. Or is there anything more to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation would be allowed to pass the iterator by const reference instead of by value. There is no relevant semantic difference.

Passing by value is slightly more efficient in this case. The `iterator` object contains a single pointer to a list element object on the heap. Remember that passing by reference is essentially passing by pointer, behind the scenes. (Although a reference is *not* the same as a pointer, when crossing an actual function call boundary, there is no other viable implementation.)

So, passing by value means the pointer-to-heap gets passed, but passing by reference means the pointer-to-`iterator` gets passed, and then two indirections are required inside the `insert` function. (This does in theory depend on the ABI, but anyway there cannot be a disadvantage to pass by value.)

A quick illustration of passing semantics:

```
template< typename param >
void same_params( param a, param b ) {
    std::cout << ( &a == &b ) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int const five = 5;
    same_params< int const & >( five, five ); // true
    same_params< int const & >( five, 6 ); // false
    same_params< int const & >( five, 5 ); // unspecified
    same_params< int const & >( 5, 5 ); // unspecified

    same_params< int >( five, five ); // false (for any arguments)
}
```

http://ideone.com/2mC07

If it weren't passing pointers, there is no way for `same_params< int const & >` to work.